# Можно ли взять данные из тегов html страницы, часть которой грузится из php?

Tags: php, html, парсер

Недавно задался вопросом, можно ли взять к примеру текст из дивов на странице, которая частично подгружается из php? 
Сначала я написал небольшой скрипт который скачивает и анализирует страницу и выдаёт инфо из тегов, но потом понял, что тегов не хватает и к примеру комменты не сохраняются...

Answer (score 0):

Для таких вещей надо использовать [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/ru/class.domdocument.php), или [Simple HTML DOM](http://sourceforge.net/projects/simplehtmldom/). Второй мне нравится чуть больше, но на больших объемах работает медленнее первого.

Comment: йо спасибо! прям то что надо! тупа лучший!!